# How to loop through all attributes and alias_attribute on all of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails app that talks to a legacy database, in which, all columns are in upper case such as `NAME`, `TYPE`, `CREATED_AT`. Providing renaming these columns to lower cases is not an option.

I understand one can use
    `alias_attribute, :new_name, :old_name`
    to create alias.

However, is there a way to loop through all the columns and alias the attributes to lower cases? Something like the following:

```
    class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
      Apple.attribtues.each do |att|
        alias_attribute :att.down_case, :att
      end
    end
```

Comment: Did my answer work?  Let me know if you still need help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` is an instance method, but `column_names` is a class method that should suit your purpose.

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
    Apple.column_names.each do |att|
      alias_attribute :att.downcase, :att
    end
  end
end
```